# Core Plot for iOS - Data labels on Bar plot are displayed twice

Tags: ios, charts, core-plot, cptbarplot

I'm fairly new to CorePlot library. In one of our app we're drawing chart's bar graphs using CorePlot.
We also display data labels for each of the Bar graph in the chart.
I'm using `labelOffset` to set its position within the bar graph (i.e. `labelOffset= -10.0`)
However, when one of the bar graph in the chart is too small to house the data label within the bar, then I'm setting `labelOffset = 10.0`, so that it can appear above the bar as default.

But, I'm seeing this weird behaviour with the CPTPlot, wherein its drawing the data label twice on the bar graph. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is a code snipet:

```
    -(CPTTextLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
    plot.labelFormatter = nil;
    plot. labelTextStyle = nil;
    if (self.showValuesAsPlotLabels)
    {
if (self.showValuesAsPlotLabels)
{
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [numberFormatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    [numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];

    CGFloat yValue = [self.chartData[index][1] floatValue];
    //return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", yValue];
    NSString *labelStr = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:@(yValue)];
    /* Check to see how tall is bar chart so that we can accordingly position data label */
    CGFloat yBaseOffsetValue = self.yAxisIntervalLength;
    CGFloat compareValue = (yBaseOffsetValue * self.divisor);
    UIColor *dataLabelColor;
    float dataLabelOffset = -10.0f;
    if (yValue > compareValue) {
        dataLabelColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        plot.labelOffset = dataLabelOffset;
    } else {
        dataLabelColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        plot.labelOffset = (0.0f - dataLabelOffset);
    }
       return [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:labelStr style:[CPTTextStyle textStyleWithAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: dataLabelColor}]];
  }

  if (self.plotLabels == nil || self.plotLabels.count < index)
  {
       return nil;
  }

   NSString *identifier = (self.plotLabels)[index];

   CPTTextLayer *label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:identifier];

   return label;
}
```

what am I missing or doing wrong here?

Thanks in adavance.

**EDIT**
After Eric's suggestion, I've tried using `plot.identifier` to check for plot specific yValues and then return `labelOffset` and `textStyle` of dataLabel accordingly. However, I see the following behaviour on the bar plot now:
[image]

I'm thinking that, `dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` is sort of using the same instance of `CPTTextLayer`? Is there a way that I can have separate instances of `CPTTextLayer` for each different `CPTBarPlot`?

---

Thanks

Comment: How many plots do you have? If more than one, make sure `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` checks the `plot` parameter and only makes labels for the correct plot.

Comment: Actually there can be 1 or more bar plots in the chart (as you can see in the screenshot). However, since there `yValues` will vary and I've to change the color and position of the dataLabel accordingly so that its visible ( see the screenshot).
How do you check for `plot` parameters to return right labels or offset?

Comment: The first parameter of the datasource method is the plot that is requesting data. Give each plot a unique `identifier` and check that in your datasource so you know which plot you're dealing with.

Comment: @EricSkroch I did provide for each bar graph with a unique identifier. However, I'm still seeing the behavior where data labels are getting drawn twice! Am I missing something here?

Comment: If the delegate will make all of the labels, make sure the plot's `labelFormatter` and `labelTextStyle` are `nil`. Otherwise, when the delegate returns `nil` for the label, it falls back to the plot's formatter to create a label.

Comment: @EricSkroch Thanks for the reponse. I've tried by making both of my bar plot's `labelFormatter` and `labelTextStyle` as `nil`, as per your suggestion. I've made both properties as `nil`, when I'm initializing the bar plots as well as in `-dataLabelForPlot...` callback.
However, it didn't help to resolve the issue. Somehow, dataLables in certain case, appear twice (or drawn twice) as shown in the first screenshot.
And I'm not returning `nil` value for any label for plot as you can see in the code snippet.
I really appreciate your help, please suggest some way so that my case will work with plot

Comment: I still think the plot is creating extra labels for the wrong plots. Can you post your code from the updated `-dataLabelForPlot:recordIndex:` method?

Comment: @EricSkroch I've updated the post with updated code snippet for `-(CPTTextLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index` datasource callback. Please take a look.

Comment: I expected to see a statement like `if ([plot.identifier isEqual:???]) …` somewhere in there. You need to make sure that you only ever create one label across all of the plots for each index.